# What is the example of a circle being filled with congruent tiles (not pie slices), with no overlap of the tiles and and no space left?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, tiling

I think I read somewhere that at one time it was thought the only way to lay tiles that would fill a circle with no overlap of the tiles and no exposed space in the cirlce, was to lay pieces that would converge at the center of the cirlce and go around the circle, the simplest example being a pie sliced in, say, eight even pieces. This was demonstrated to be false by a circle with congruent tiles that weren't all rotated about the center. What did this pattern look like.

Sorry if I'm not being clear or if I'm not remembering correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See here for some examples of rather "nontrivial" dissections: https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2012/12/20/dissecting-the-disc/

Comment: With the pie slices, what happens to the center of the circle?

Comment: @GerryMeyerson The interiors of the tiles are required to be disjoint, not the boundaries.  Otherwise none of these tilings would work.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17313/is-it-possible-to-dissect-a-disk-into-congruent-pieces-so-that-a-neighborhood-o (although that url is currently giving me an error message, but Google has the page cached so you can see it deals with essentially the same question as this one).